# Cannot login to Kali Linux

Tags: linux, user-accounts, login, liveusb, kali-linux

I just created a **Kali 1.0.6** live USB using a tool called "*Mac Linux USB Loader*" and everything seems fine up until the point where you are supposed to login.
At the login screen I'm greeted with the choice of user "*Other*" where I have to manually enter at username and password.
The problem is that I have not created a user or set any password, and **"root" as user and "toor" as password doesn't work.**

### EDIT

I reinstalled Kali and got it working, I did it like this:

1. My friend installed Kali on his USB-drive, using normal install process inside his Linux OS
2. We plugged his USB into my Macbook and booted from it
3. I plugged in my USB which I wanted Kali Live on
4. Using my friend's Kali Live (that we booted into) we opened the terminal and used a command called "dd" which copies everything from one location to another. Done!

Comment: You should have specified a password when you installed the system.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Perhaps I should, but there really was no installation since it's a live USB.

Comment: When you say you have tried default. Did you select "other" and put "root" and "toor"?

Comment: A small detail: is it a **Persistent** *Live USB*?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Yes.

Comment: Super User's purpose is to create a knowledgebase, and it relies on a structure that questions are questions and answers are answers.  A question that contains its own answer prevents the normal site usage mechanisms from working (e.g., there is no way for search for or handle your solution as an answer).  So that others can benefit from your solution, could you move your edit to an answer (you're allowed to answer your own question)?  Then accepting your answer will flag that it has been solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem although a slight difference was I installed in Virtual Box. 
When ask during the install for a admin/root password I created one. 
After the install and reboot I was ask for a user/other and password in order to log in. root and toor were not working
After several failed tries I finally logged in using root as the user and the **password** I created during setup.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Worry...!

**STEP 1:** Wait till GRUB LOADER and SELECT (RECOVERY MODE) and hit <kbd>e</kbd> to EDIT...

**STEP 2:** Add this line as below -> **`init=/bin/bash`**
[image]

**Step 3:** Then PRESS <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to BOOT....

**Step 4:** After booted, TYPE **`fdisk -l`** which will display the partitions **(the one with the * is root partition)** as below:
[image]

**Step 5:** NOW, TYPE **`mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /`**

**Step 6:** NOW, TYPE the **`passwd`** command to complete the password reset!!! and (`exit` or restart your system / in VirtualBox press <kbd>Host key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reset the system)

Now you can log in with your new password!

Comment: But the original poster refers to a "Live USB Kali", probably with no persistence. Each time you reboot, the changes will be deleted.

Comment: This worked for me after having problems installing from a live usb. I had to copy files to disk and **then*** install, after which the `root` `toor` combination didnt work. Your password reset saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Select `Other` user
2. Use `root` as the username
3. Enter the root administrator password you entered during the install.

Comment: I think that OP tried that and didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- root/live
- user/live

If that doesn't work, it is supposed that you could **chroot into your live USB** and set a new password with `passwd root`. Instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121066/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-live-filesystem-squashfs-linux-distribution); the process is not complex, but the mounting of filesystems will probably be long (maybe a few hours).

EDIT: removed suggestion tu use the specified password during installation.
EDIT 2: added new solution: chroot into your Llive USB.

Comment: The OP already specified he doesn't have the password and the default password as stated in Kali documentation is toor, which the OP has already tried.

Comment: @sopalajo I tried those without any success.

Comment: As a (no much chances) possibility: try login from text console (Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Comment: Upsss... you were right, @MatthewWilliams. I have edited to solve.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez We tried that today, also with no luck

Comment: Well, I have edited my post to add a new solution: editing your Live USB using `chroot`. Hope it will work for you. Ask if you need some help.

Answer (score 0):

After Version 2020.1 the root user is locked. You need to login with
Username: kali
Password: kali
If you need to use the root account, open terminal and run
`sudo passwd root`
Then you can login as root.